# How to pass a range of validResponseCodes for Jenkins pipeline httpRequest method

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How to pass a range of `validResponseCodes` for Jenkins pipeline's `httpRequest` method?

Here is the reference for this method:
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/#httprequest-perform-an-http-request-and-return-a-response-object

Documentation says its a string. And no more examples are provided.

I would like the valid response codes to be 200 - 400 and build not to fail because of the response code 400.

Answer (score 10):

`validResponseCodes` should be an interval from:to or a single value.
In your case it would be

```
httpRequest url: someUrl, validResponseCodes: '200:400'
```

See [HttpRequest](https://github.com/jenkinsci/http-request-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/http_request/HttpRequest.java) class for more information.

Also, based on the source code, it looks like it's possible to specify ranges and singe values separated by a comma. e.g. `200:400,409`

Comment: Wow! I bet if anyone can guess this out from the informative documentation. Thanks!

Comment: What to do if the right set of codes is discontiguous? Like 200:400,409?

Comment: @Lonnie based on the source code you can list ranges and singe values separated by a comma. e.g. `200:400,409`. However, I haven't tried it.